# Birt report I can't able to set type as US Legal

Tags: eclipse, birt

In birt report, how to make type as US legal. In master page, I have given type as us legal, but while exporting type as becoming  a4. Can anyone please help me..

Comment: While exporting in xlsx it is not coming properly

Comment: In xls it is coming fine